# How to manage multi port by .htacceess?

Tags: .htaccess, port

My backend is node and listen on port 8000 , 4200. 
handle one port with this code.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 4200
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:4200/$1 [P,L]
```

I can't manage port simultaneous.

Comment: can you explain what ports 8000 and 4200 are meant for? doesn't make sense to redirect port 4200 to 4100 imho

Comment: i need these two ports for run a nodeJs app.